# How can I target specific iPad devices with CSS3 media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm creating a responsive landing page and when I test it in different tablet devices, there are adjustments I want to make (paddings, margins, etc).  I managed to target the normal breakpoints but I need to target more specific ones such as:

- iPad Mini - 768 x 1024 with 324ppi
- iPad 10 - 810 x 1080 with 264ppi
- iPad 9 - 768 x 1024 with 264ppi

Can I get this specific? When I try, it ends up messing up my non-ipad media queries.

Answer (score 0):

use media query with same parameters like

`@media screen and (max-width:768px)`  will works for and iPad 9

`@media screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-resolution: 300dpi)`  will works for iPad Mini

`@media screen and (max-width:810px)` will works for iPad 10

Comment: I understand, but if I use what you suggest, it will affect other sizes as well :(

Comment: targeting different dpi could not solve problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be as specific as you can, try setting the min and max widths, as well as device orientation and pixel ratio:
`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (orientation: portrait)`

For more you can check this article: [Popular Devices Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)